# Privacy that a scheme offers

Tags: data-privacy, standards

I encountered the following scenario in development of a system.

A user wants to perform an operation on one of $n$ days. An adversary can observe a sequence of integers $X_1, \cdots, X_n$. If the user performs the operation on day $i$, then $X_i$ will be sampled according to distribution $Q$, while all $X_j(j \neq i)$ will be sampled according to distribution $P$.

The user does not wish the adversary to learn which day the user performs the operation.

Question: given $P, Q$, is there a way to quantify the "privacy" of this scheme offers?

Example: if $P = Q$, then the scheme has perfect privacy. If $P,Q$ have disjoint support, then the scheme has no privacy, since the adversary can be certain which day the user performs the operation.

Example case I'm interested in: $P$ is uniformly random over $\{0, 1\}$, $Q$ is Bernoulli over $\{0,1\}$ with $P(Q = 0) = \frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if $P, Q$ are identical or statistically or computationally indistinguishable, your system achieves perfect, statistical and computational security accordingly. Anything else offers none of the above. If you have any specific security definition in mind I would love to discuss about it. The example you mentioned offers no security, because security isn't measured as a single instance of the random variable, it is instead measured on the probability distribution itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On second thought, I believe I could take $P, Q$ to be two families of distributions $P_{\lambda}, Q_{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the security parameter. e.g. $Q_{\lambda}$ is Bernoulli with $P(Q_{\lambda}) = 1/2 + \lambda^{-1}$. Can we measure security in this case?

Comment: Yes, but only if for example in the case of computational indistinguishability their distance is negligible. For example, $λ^{-1}$ is non negligible, $2^{-λ}$ would work for example, again this is for computational indistinguishability.